# bash script to accept log on stdin and email log if inputting process fails

Tags: bash, pipe, exit, status

I'm a sysadmin and I frequently have a situation where I have a script or command that generates a lot of output which I would only like to have emailed to me if the command fails.  It's pretty easy to write a script that runs the command, collects the output and emails it if the command fails, but I was thinking I should be able to write a command that

1) accepts log info on stdin
2) waits for the inputting process to exit and see what it's exit status was
3a) if the inputting process exited cleanly, append the logging input to a normal log file
3b) if the inputting process failed, append the logging input to the normal log and also send me an email.

It would look something like this on the command line:

```
something_important | mailonfail.sh me@example.com /var/log/normal_log
```

That would make it really easy to use in crontabs.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make my script wait for the writing process and evaluate how that process exits.

Just to be exatra clear, here's how I can do it with a wrapper:

```
#! /bin/bash

something_important > output
ERR=$!

if [ "$ERR" -ne "0" ] ; then
  cat something_important | mail -s "something_important failed" me@example.com
fi
cat something_important >> /var/log/normal_log
```

Again, that's not what I want, I want to write a script and pipe commands into it.

Does that make sense?  How would I do that?  Am I missing something?

Thanks Everyone!
-Dylan

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does make sense, and you are close.

Here are some advises:

```
#!/bin/sh

TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $TEMPFILE" EXIT

if [ ! something_important > $TEMPFILE ]; then
  mail -s 'something goes oops' -a $TEMPFILE you@example.net
fi
cat $TEMPFILE >> /var/log/normal.log
```

- I won't use bashisms so /bin/sh is fine
- create a temporary file to avoid conflicts using [`mktemp(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mktemp.1.html)
- use `trap` to remove file when the script exit, normally or not
- if the command fail
- then attach the file, which would or would not be preferred over embedding it

  - if it's a big file you could even gzip it, but the attachment method will change:

    ```
    # using mailx
    gzip -c9 $TEMPFILE | uuencode fail.log.gz | mailx -s subject ...

    # using mutt
    gzip $TEMPFILE
    mutt -a $TEMPFILE.gz -s ...
    gzip -d $TEMPFILE.gz
    ```

etc.

Comment: You are a lovely human being and that is a lovely answer, but that's the thing I already know how to do.  I give you +1 anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry it seems I didn't fully understood your question... Was it about how to wait for a given time a command (killing it if it's too slow)? I'm not sure either about the "a script and pipe commands into it"?

Comment: I want to be able to do "./some_command | myscript.sh" and have myscript.sh know if some_command exited ok or not.